# Redirect to opportunity edit page

Tags: apex, visualforce, opportunity, new

I have 2 user profiles: **internal user** and **partner user** (partner portal). I want to have separate behaviours when each user clicks on the Opportunity **New** button, to create a new opportunity:

- **internal** user clicks on Opportunity New button - redirect to a custom visualforce page;
- **partner** user clicks on Opportunity New button - redirect to a custom the standard opportunity edit page;

I have:

1. replaced the standard "New" button with my custom VF page;
2. in the VF page I've added an action to check and redirect to the correct page;
3. in the controller, the method checks the context user and if it's a partner user, redirects to the standard opportunity edit page.

This works fine for internal user; for the partner user, it does redirect to the standard page but, for some reason, it gets into some kind of loop and the page never actually loads.

I wonder if the link I am redirecting to is correct or if there's something I am doing wrong.

Here's a snippet of the code:

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OpportunityController" tabStyle="Opportunity" action="{!redirectForPartner}">

</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public PageReference redirectForPartner(){

    User user;
    Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();

    if(userId != null){
        user = [Select Id, Name, Email, Username, ProfileId, Profile.Name From User Where Id =: userId];
    }

    if(user.Profile.Name.equals(PARTNER_PROFILE)){

        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/partner/006/e?retURL=%2Fpartner%2F006%2Fo');
        return pr;

    }

    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have done all of this without any apex code at all:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" 
  action="{!IF($Profile.Name=$Label.Partner_Profile_Name, 
    URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.New, null, null, true),
    URLFOR($Page.NewOpportunity, null, null)}"></apex:page>
```

I'd recommend having the custom Visualforce page be separate so that the redirect is on its own page. It's a little easier to manage this way.

Comment: Did you mean `$Action` instead of `$ObjectType` getting error `ApexPagesDescribeSObjectResult.New` - Nice tip, thanks

Comment: @Eric Yeah, I did.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox! Yes, this was definately what I was aiming for. Best!

Comment: @Eric - Thanks to you as well Eric. $Action was the correct one. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop the override by using the `nooverride` parameter.

Change as follows:

```
if(user.Profile.Name.equals(PARTNER_PROFILE)){

    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/partner/006/e?retURL=%2Fpartner%2F006%2Fo&nooverried=1');
    return pr;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so with the help of @sfdcfox and @Eric, I think I got the answer. I had to tweak the action a little bit.

2 things I had to change:

1) I needed to add a retURL to this `URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.New, null, null, true)` because the Cancel button on the standard page wasn't doing anything.

2) I replaced this `URLFOR($Page.NewOpportunity, null, null)})}` for `null`, because I was getting one of those strange Internal Errors from Salesforce. I think because the page was calling itself, it might've entered some kind of loop.

I ended up with this:

```
action="{!IF($Profile.Id==PARTNER_PROFILE_ID, URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.New, null, [retURL='/006/o'], true), null)}"
```

It looks like it's working :)

Cheers